# RSpec using wrong attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd

Instead of passing in a submission's id, RSpec is passing in the submission's title. Any suggestions?

All errors and files are here: https://gist.github.com/maclover7/c6533d0b7e4cd7ad2322

error message

```
Failure/Error: put :update, hackathon_id: create(:hackathon), submission_id: @submission, submission: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:submission), :format => :json, :access_token => @token.token
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
   Couldn't find Submission with 'id'=Dolorum ipsa officiis velit et id quo ea.
 # ./app/controllers/api/v1/submissions_controller.rb:60:in `set_submission'
 # ./spec/controllers/api/v1/submissions_controller_spec.rb:88:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Based on this, it seems like there is something wrong with the set_submission before_action, right? But, it is standard Rails procedure, so I'm not sure what the issue is here.

submisisons_controller.rb

```
# Relevant action
private
 def set_submission
   @submission = Submission.find(params[:submission_id])
 end
```

submissions_controller_spec.rb (relevant parts)

```
describe "PUT #update" do
  before :each do
    @oauth_application = FactoryGirl.build(:oauth_application)
    @token = Doorkeeper::AccessToken.create!(:application_id => @oauth_application.id, :resource_owner_id => user.id)
    @submission = FactoryGirl.build(:submission)
  end

  context "valid attributes" do
    it "located the requested @submission" do
      put :update, hackathon_id: create(:hackathon), submission_id: @submission, submission: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:submission), :format => :json, :access_token => @token.token
      assigns(:submission).should eq(@submission)
    end

    it "changes @submission's attributes" do
      put :update, hackathon_id: create(:hackathon), submission_id: @submission, submission: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:submission, tagline: "lala"), :format => :json, :access_token => @token.token
      @submission.reload
      @submission.tagline.should eq("lala")
    end

    it "sends a 200 if updated submission if correct_user" do
      if @submission.user_id == user.id
        put :update, hackathon_id: create(:hackathon), submission_id: @submission, submission: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:submission), :format => :json, :access_token => @token.token
        response.status.should eq(200)
      else
        response.status.should eq(401)
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Try changing `submission_id: @submission` to `submission_id: @submission.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. Need to make sure
`@submission = FactoryGirl.create(:submission)`, which will then let you call an id on the submission, `submission_id: @submission.id`.